# How to find an invisible window in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, gnome-shell

Sometimes when I open files in LibreOffice, they open in minimized windows that I cannot find anywhere on my screen. How can I find the windows and resize them?

The files still appear if I click on the LibreOffice icon in the dock (see attached screenshot; file names pixellated for privacy), but no thumbnail appears and clicking on the minimized file does not cause the file to appear or have any other apparent result.

[image]

Notes: (1) This started happening recently. I don't know if I made a change that caused it, if it was related to an update, or if it has some other cause. (2) It happens primarily when I open a file from the web in LibreOffice, by clicking on the "open in LibreOffice" button in the download popup in Firefox. I'm not sure whether it happens under other circumstances as well. (3) Restarting Ubuntu fixes the problem, in that I can then open the file in question to a visible window. But it is not a permanent solution, as the problem recurs with other files.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you using Xorg or Wayland sessions?

Comment: @ToDo: I'm using X11.

Comment: Then there's an easier way to recover without rebooting. Alt + F2, r, Enter

Comment: @ToDo: This does not appear to do anything. If run at the command line, "r" returns "Command 'r' not found, but can be installed with: [references to the R statistical packages]." Which "r" are you referring to?

Comment: You should run it at the command line, but in the Alt + F2 run command dialog box. It's a shortcut to some longer command to reset the X server.